# What is mean cannonical cover?

Tags: rdbms

I am new to DBMS.

I am learning  the concept of integrity constraints.
In this topic, i have a one sub topic.
That is functional dependency.
I am not able to understand this topic.

Please explain with examples for the following questions.

1. What is Meant by functional dependency and what is the use of this in DBMS?
2. What is meant by canonical cover and what is the use of this and how to find the canonical cover in the given relation?

Thanks for advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A canonical cover for F is a set of dependencies such that F logically implies all dependencies in tex2html_wrap_inline1324 , and vice versa.

Answer (score 0):

The [wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Canonical_cover) says about the cannocial cover:

> A canonical cover F_c for F (a set of functional dependencies on a
>   relation scheme) is a set of dependencies such that F logically
>   implies all dependencies in F_c, and F_c logically implies all
>   dependencies in F.

and [Functional dependency](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Functional_dependency):

> In relational database theory, a functional dependency is a constraint
>   between two sets of attributes in a relation from a database.

Comment: Please explain what is meant by functional dependency?

Comment: @sureshkumar:- You can simply type those terms on Google and you can get the answer. See [here](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/dbms/database_normalization.htm): `Functional dependency (FD) is a set of constraints between two attributes in a relation. Functional dependency says that if two tuples have same values for attributes A1, A2,..., An, then those two tuples must have to have same values for attributes B1, B2, ..., Bn.`

Answer (score 0):

To minimize the number of functional dependencies that need to be tested in case of an update we may restrict F to a canonical cover tex2html_wrap_inline1324 .

A canonical cover for F is a set of dependencies such that F logically implies all dependencies in tex2html_wrap_inline1324 , and vice versa.

A canonical cover Fc for F is a set of dependencies such that F logically implies all dependencies in Fc, and Fc logically implies all dependencies in F.

The set Fc has two important properties:

```
No functional dependency in Fc contains an extraneous attribute.

Each left side of a functional dependency in Fc is unique.
```